# What is bounded height in ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, layout, markup, yoga-x1

What does it mean? (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview)

> Keep in mind that **ScrollViews** must have a bounded height in order to work

Who has to have so called *bounded height*? `ScrollView` itself? or its very parent? Or its child?

```
<SafeAreaView style={{height: ...}}> <= this?
    <ScrollView style={{height: ...}}> <= this?
        <View style={{height: ...}}> <= this?
            ....
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: it means the inner view inside of the ScrollView should have a height of its own filled data! WRAP CONTENT

Comment: @Rizwanatta, what does it mean _a height of its own_?

Comment: ScrollView is a generic view that depends upon the height go the screen in which it is being rendered! and in ScrollView it takes only one Child Whose height should be wrapContent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know its height of parent of ScrollView.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
     ......
     ......
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
       flex: 1,
     },
```